# ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1

Tags: linux, iptables, load-balancing, high-availability

I am trying  to create a web cluster with two load balancers and a single public ip address

The command I use is the following:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d $CLUSTERIP   -i $WAN_IF -j CLUSTERIP --new --clustermac $CLUSTERMAC --total-nodes $TOTALNODES --local-node $LOCALNODE --hashmode sourceip-sourceport
```

I am losing about 10% of requests and I do not know the reason. On the first node dmesg says:

```
[3953663.740770] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
[3958608.863834] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
[3959598.791987] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
[3962373.974935] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
[3964028.213515] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
[3964884.100071] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
[3969131.737498] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
[3971028.349664] ipt_CLUSTERIP: unknown protocol 1
```

Do you have any idea where I should look to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue recently. Supposed to be is not a packets losing in fact, it have to be invalid packets I guess. One of ClusterIP howtos suggests just to filter them out.

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```